# Using base36/unique ID in Rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using RoR 2.3.8.

I have tried `to_param`, friendly_id, and in the end, I find that I will have real headaches in Unicode conversion when my site goes international. I am planning to have contents with lots of languages, accented, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc. So instead of putting those titles in my URL, I am planning to sacrifice it. Yeah, I just want an ID in it.

Now I want to implement something like YouTube, where each video URL ends with a unique ID. Let's say an entry with `ID=10` will have a unique ID:

`http://abc.com/shops/rD4g35tQ`

I want the URL to be permanent.

I don't know how to go about it. Can someone show me some examples or give me some heads up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can [Base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) encode the IDs. 36 is a good radix to use because the digits can be represented using the numbers 0-9 and the letters A-Z.

```
# Example with ID = 10. Convert from Base 10 to Base 36
id = 10
id.to_s(36) #=> "a"

# Convert from Base 36 back to Base 10
"a".to_i(36) #=> 10
```

- Further details in my blog post: [Write A Web App In Nine Lines Of Code With Sinatra](http://johntopley.com/2009/11/14/write-a-web-app-in-nine-lines-of-code-with-sinatra/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate UUIDs, this lib will help you:
https://github.com/assaf/uuid

The only thing you have to do is put a before_create to assign a new uuid to your object and you are done.