# Encode rails model id in URLs with base36

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, base36

I’m trying to encode the model id for a rails app using base36 following the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792715/using-base36-unique-id-in-rails-url)
but I am unsure as to what I need to do.

Where do I put `id.to_s(36)`? Do I need to add a column to my database?

I’d like to have my URLs to be `domain.com/user/rD4g35tQ` instead of `domain.com/user/3`.

Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.16

Here is my show action in my controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Edit: Here is my create action:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to_param is for this.  It is used by the routing to generate paths.  By default it returns an object's id, but you can override it in a model to be anything you want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    id.to_s(36)
  end

end
```

In controllers, params[:id] will now be the string you wanted, but you'll need to convert back to the real primary key:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id].to_i(36))
end
```

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested but it doesn't have an effect on the URL. It still shows domain.com/user/:id. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working! I needed to update another action in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would create a unique column, for example 'uuid', in the users table to store the encoded string and query a user with it.

in config/routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

in app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.where(uuid: params[:uuid]).first
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    redirect_to new_user_path
  end
end
```

Actually, the reason to use an encoded string instead of the id is for the security concern. I suggest not using the base36 encoding for this purpose. You can use a random string and assign it when a user is created, for example:

in app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_readonly :uuid

  before_validation :gen_uuid, on: :create

  validates :uuid, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  # ...

  def to_param
    self.uuid
  end

  private
  def gen_uuid
    self.uuid = RandomToken.genf(32)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

The disadvantage of a customized route is to lose the `_url` and `_path` helpers, the better way is to keep the original routes created by `resources` and use Tim's answer to override the `to_param`.

Comment: I'm getting an error `uninitialized constant User::RandomToken` in my users_controller under the create action. I have updated my question to include the create action. I am using `resouces :users` in my routes. Would this cause any problems with `get 'user/:uuid', to: 'users#show'`? Thanks for the help.

Comment: RandomToken is a gem to create a random token, you can just use other way to create your own token. I take user/:uuid for example is to make a difference with the original one. Actually, you can still use resources :user and pass the uuid with user/:id.

Comment: BTW, with the user model I listed in the answer, you don't need to assign uuid on your own, it would be assigned automatically when a user is created.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it's a bit messy losing the `_url` and `_path` helpers.